# Incorrect path file reference to packages when sharing solution between mac and windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have solution/flutter app running on **windows** fine.  Within the .packages file vscode is referencing the package via

```
analyzer:file:///c:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.31.2-alpha.2/lib/
args:file:///c:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.4.3/lib/
async:file:///c:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.0.7/lib/
...
```

I have the flutter sdk installed c:\flutter directory on windows.

I copied this solution via dropbox to the **mac** and when running

"Warning! This package referenced a Flutter repository via the .packages file that is no longer available".

In an effort to isolate/locate the problem, I created a new Flutter project on the mac and found that the .packages file referenced packages via

```
analyzer:file:///flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.31.2-alpha.2/lib/
args:file:///flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.4.3/lib/
async:file:///flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.0.7/lib/
...
```

**Notice** the different paths used on both systems.

I suspect I can search/replace the references file:///c:/flutter to file:///flutter and it should work but I would like to avoid always manually swapping out locations.  Is there an easier approach when sharing solutions across mac and windows?

thx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't copy `.packages` over from one machine to another. (It should be in `.gitignore` if using git.)

Instead, run `flutter packages get` on the mac, and it will recreate `.packages`.

(Don't copy `.flutter-plugins` either.)

Comment: Also you have to delete .flutter-plugins-dependencies

Answer (score 7):

Just remove `.packages` file. It will do the trick. Or you can clear the `.packages` file.

Comment: This worked for me. Deleted .packages file and ran pubs get

Comment: Where do i find the .packages file, cant locate it in root

Comment: @LimoFlasch You can find it in your flutter project root directory. In mac os dot(.) files are hidden by default. To make them visible press Command+Shift+Dot.

Comment: Okay, I am on windows. Do I have to search in the flutter directory or the project from AndroidStudioProjects, first time!

Comment: @LimoFlasch Yeah, you should be able to find it in file system or in any IDE file heirarchy

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the package (flutter create tempapp) on my c:\vsc-flutter projects directory.  my flutter bin is at c:\src\flutter .  I then copied the .packages folder to the directory of the damaged .packages file in the source project